# Numbering Theorems with section number but not resetting the counter

Tags: sectioning, theorems, counters

I want to number theorems in the form "Theorem 1.4.26", such that the first two numbers are the chapter and section numbers and the last one is the number of the theorem in the whole book. That is, the counter for the last one does not reset through sections and chapters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you use? Do you use a theorem-styling package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem`? Which numbering system is being employed currently?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming no package concerning theorem-like environments is loaded, the counter associated with a theorem environment is incremented monotonically *unless* a final optional argument of the `\newtheorem` command is provided. I.e.,

```
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}
```

defines a theorem environment and an associated counter, both named `mytheorem`. In contrast,

```
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
```

would define the same environment, but with the `mytheorem` counter being reset every time the counter named `chapter` is changed.

The final thing to solve is the way the counter variable associated with the theorem environment is displayed. Your formatting objective may be acheived by issuing the instruction `\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{First}
\begin{mytheorem}
Foo
\end{mytheorem}


\chapter{Second}
\section{First in Second}
\begin{mytheorem}
Foobar
\end{mytheorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg: True, I confused the additions of `amsthm` with the standard environment. Removed the reference to `amsthm`. Thanks

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your posting a bit.

Comment: @Mico: Hm, was it really necessary?

Comment: I may have gotten carried away a bit. :-( Sorry. Feel free to revert.